# javascript set promise callback after the promise had finished execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

In the following snippet I am trying to set the `Promise` callback *after* the promise is supposed to be finished.

For some reason, it seems to "remember" to execute the callback after I expect the future to finish it's execution.

Why is it so?

```js
 
 'use strict';
 var promiseCount = 0;
 
 function testPromise() {
  var thisPromiseCount = ++promiseCount;

  var log = document.getElementById('log');
  log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
   ') Started (<small>Sync code started</small>)<br/>');

  // We make a new promise: we promise the string 'result' (after waiting 3s)
  var p1 = new Promise(
   // The resolver function is called with the ability to resolve or
   // reject the promise
   function(resolve, reject) {
   
    log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
     ')  the promise is started(<small>Async code started</small>)<br/>');
    
    resolve(thisPromiseCount);

    log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',promiseCount+ ') the promise is supposed to finish<br/>');
     
   });

   window.setTimeout(
    function() {
       log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
        ') we set the callback much after the proise has finished<br/>');
     p1.then(
      // Log the fulfillment value
      function(val) {
       log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val +
        ') and still the promise executes the callback!(<small>Async code terminated</small>)<br/>');
      })
     .catch(
      // Log the rejection reason
      function(reason) {
       console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
      });
    }, 5000);

  log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
   ') Sync code terminated<br/>');
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick='testPromise()' />test</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `p` is an already resolved promise and you then call `p.then(callback)`, it will still call the callback.  That's how promises are specified to work.  This is as expected.

But, the `.then()` callback will be called asynchronously after the thread of execution that did the `p.then()` has finished executing (in other words, it won't be called immediately, but after a slight delay).  This is so that `.then()` handlers are always executed asynchronously whether the promise they are called on is still pending or already resolved.  This creates consistent programming behavior.

Here's a little bit simpler demo:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    log("Creating promise");
    resolve();
});

log("Promise Created");

log("Calling p.then()");

p.then(function() {
    log("In .then() handler");
})
    
log("After calling p.then()");    


function log(msg) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

You can run the snippet to see the output as:

> ```
> Creating promise
> Promise Created
> Calling p.then()
> After calling p.then()
> In .then() handler
> ```

In words, it does the following:

1. Calls the `new Promise()` constructor
2. The Promise constructor calls the callback
3. Logs "Creating Promise"
4. The callback resolves the promise
5. Logs "Promise Created"
6. Logs "Calling p.then()"
7. Calls `p.then()` on the resolved promise.  Since the promise is already resolved, this schedules the `.then()` callback to run as soon as this current thread of execution is done.
8. Logs "After calling p.then()"
9. Current thread of execution finishes and then the promise calls the `.then()` handler
10. The `.then()` handler logs "In .then() handler"